# My thread disappears from thread list after some time

Tags: c#, multithreading, producer-consumer

I have multi thread program with C# language.
When load main form, 4 thread start that all of them work with `while(true)`
Every thread run, active and exist in thread list but after 30 ms, one of thread (without any error) disappear from thread list and doesn't work
even breakpoint not work.
I want read data from TCP and process 3 steps then save to database

- Task1: have `while(true)` and read data from tcp and add to blockingcollection bk1
- Task 2: in `while(true)`, take data from bk1 and process data then add data to `BlockingCollection` bk2
- Task3 in `while(true)` take data from bk2 and process then bk3
- Task 4 in `while (true)` take data from bk3 then insert database

I define task:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => myfunction, CancellationToken.None,
    TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness, TaskScheduler.Default);
```

When click button1 all of tasks start and work correctly after some time task3 change status to `RanToCompletion` and does not work I didn't use async and await in code because task works parallel and don't need wait for other task.

Even `TaskCreationOptions` set to `LongRunning` 
My function have `while(true)` and work producer-consumer method.

Please help me about problem.
Thanks for attention.

Comment: did you mean to write `myfunction` instead of `() => myfunction`? Looks like you're passing in a lambda that returns your function (and nothing else, not invoking it)

Comment: Also note that C# is case-sensitive - this code won't compile, which means it isn't your *actual* code. We don't know what other differences there are between your real code and what you've posted. It would be helpful if you'd provide a [mcve]...

Comment: The most likely explanation is that your task is throwing an exception, which you are not observing because you never `await` the task.

Comment: Could you add try/catch wrapper for entire `myfunction` body? That would help you understand is there any exception raised (and then silently discarded)

Answer (score 2):

Your code never awaits that task to end. Use `await` and `Task.Run` instead:

```
await Task.Run(()=>myFunction());
```

or

```
await Task.Run(myFunction);
```

Tasks aren't threads. They're a job that gets executed by a threadpoool thread. Creating a thread is an expensive operation. To avoid the cost of creating and destroying threads, .NET keeps a pool of worker threads. Jobs, in the form of Action or Func delegates, get posted to that ThreadPool and executed by one of the worker threads.

`Task.Run` or `Task.Factor.StartNew` post a job to the threadpool for execution and return a `Task`, essentially a "promise" object. This means the calling thread isn't blocked waiting for the task to complete and can do other work. `await` makes it easy to await for that task to complete and get back to the calling thread. Once the task completes, execution can resume with the code after `await`.

In a desktop application that means the UI thread doesn't get blocked waiting for a task to complete and can keep processing Windows messages, button clicks, refresh its windows etc. When the task completes, execution will resume on the UI thread with the code that comes after `await`.

```
async void btn1_Click(object sender,EventArgs args)
{
    var customerName=txtCustomer.Text;
    var orders=await Task.Run(()=>LoadOrdersFromDbAsync(customerName));
    grdOrders.DataSource=orders;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. My task 1 produce data and add to blockingcollection  and task2 take data ,process and produce data and data to queue then task 3 take data from queue , process and add to queue then task4 take data and process and insert to database all of them task have while true and dont return any thing and should run continuse i can not await for task